# Determine whether an error is random?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, standard-deviation

We have two measurements of the temperature of the same object as: $T_1 = 46 \pm 2 F$ and $T_2 = 58 \pm 6 F$.
Normally, the agreement between the measurements could shown to a standard deviation by taking their average: $52 \pm \sqrt{36+4}$.

What would the best approach to determine whether the disagreement is due to random measurement error and not to physical change in the object's actual temperature ? Is this best explained in terms of probabilities? Please explain.

Comment: Totally lost on this: (a) $T_1$ and $T_2$ seem contradictory. (b) What is the rationale for averaging? (c) In what way is $58\pm\sqrt{36+16}$ an average of quantities in (a)? (d) Is what follows $\pm$ a standard deviation or a margin of error? (e) What about $54\pm 10?$

Comment: Sorry for the confusion the third expression should be $52 \pm \sqrt{36+4}$ for averaging of both measurements. I just need a way to answer the question: What would the best approach to determine whether the disagreement is due to random measurement error and not to physical change in the object's actual temperature ?

Comment: "Normally" the measurements, assuming they are independent, would be combined with a weighted average where the relative weights are $1/2^2$ and $1/6^2,$ respectively (giving the best estimate as $47.2$ degrees rather than $52$ degrees).  Your question about "best approach" cannot be answered until you answer the rest of @Bruce's questions.

Comment: $58 \pm 6$ implies out of a sample of thermal measurements, most commonly we measured 58, and the min/max were 52/64 respectively. Not sure what Bruce means by $54 \pm 10$. To make things a little more clear, imagine we conducted 2 different experiments on different occasions on an object whose temperature is constant and unchanged during both experiments. What would be a good way, for someone who does not know the object's actual temperature, to determine whether the error is actual difference in the object's temperature or due to measurement, based off the 2 measurements provided above